# Expressing a vector as a sum of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix and $x$ be arbitrary vector. Show that $x$ can be written as $x = \sum y_i$, where each $y_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_i$ are all different.

I would be glad for any help with this problem.

Comment: you mean $x= \sum_i \alpha_i y_i$?

Comment: @asdf If $y$ is an eigenvector, then $ay$ is an eigenvector as well.

Comment: of course, indeed the scalar for forming a linear combination are missing.

Comment: @asdf My point is that the scalars aren't missing; rather, they are redundant.

Comment: mmm, I see. but why? you need to change the basis for each new vector you want to express in the eigenbasis..

Comment: @asdf Well, the question explicitly asks "show that for every $x$ there exist $y_i$ such that...", so naturally the $y_i$ depend on $x$.

Comment: This is true in the case that $A$ is diagonalizable. What do you think being hermitian and positive definiteness? Use the fact that all hermitian matrices are diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real positive-definite matrix is necessarily symmetric, thus diagonalizable, thus possesses a basis of eigenvectors, so any vector can be written as $x=\sum y_i$ with $y_i$ eigenvectors. Summing all $y_i$ with the same eigenvalue is still an eigenvector with this same eigenvalue, so we can make the $y_i$ in the sum to have different eigenvalues.

Comment: It's should be simple to see that if you sum two eigenvector, you will not obtain an eigenvector...

Comment: @asdf In general — yes. However, summing eigenvectors that correspond to the same eigenvalue produces an eigenvector.

Comment: Really? Let's take the identity matrix, all eigenvalues are 1. Take two of the canonical basis [1,0,..] and [0,1,0,0...]. Is this really an eigenvector?

Comment: @asdf Yes, the sum of [1,0,...,0] and [0,1,0...,0] is [1,1,0,...,0], which is clearly an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. In fact, for the identity matrix, any nonzero vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1, because $Ix=x=1\cdot x$.

Comment: @lisyarus use "hermitian" instead of symmetric. That word is more comprehensive.

Comment: @RedPhoenix It isn't more comprehensive, it is just different: a real symmetric matrix becomes both hermitian and complex symmetric after complexification; complex hermitian isn't necessarily symmetric. Since nothing in the question suggests complex numbers, I'm assuming the real case here. I'll edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: @lisyarus All real symmetric matrices are hermitian. but not all symmetric matrices are hermitian. That's why i say hermitian is more comprehensive. For example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & i\\ i & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is symmetric but not hermitian. However its roots are not even real. All hermitian matrices have real roots, if all of them are positive then we call positive definite. That term is not restricted to real cases.

Comment: @RedPhoenix You basically rephrased my whole comment. Again, as nothing in the question indicates the (arguably more advanced) complex hermitian case, I assume the real symmetric case. After all, the OP may not even be familiar with the notion of hermitian matrix.